# How map and filter over array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

sorry guys but i have a dummy question..
i need to iterate objects from a json response and obtain only those how meet some conditions..
the response is like this:

```
  result = [
      {
        "type": "EVENT",
        "id": "001",
        "tags": [
            {
            "id": "98765",
            "name": "home"
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "EVENT",
        "id": "002",
        "tags": [
            {
            "id": "7654",
            "name": "contact"
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "EVENT",
        "id": "003",
        "tags": []
      }
    ]
```

I need to use only those whose type is 'event' and name properties in tags be home.

I tried map and filter, but I do not get the desired result

```
const eventType = result.filter(type => type.type == 'EVENT')
 const nameFilter = 
    eventType.map(item => item.tags)
    .filter(sub => sub.length) // remove empty []
    .map(subarray => subarray.map(element =>  element.name )
    .filter(element => element == 'home'));
```

result:

```
 [
  ['home'], // dosen t work for me, because need all the object
  [],
  []
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` to loop thru the array. Use `some` to check if at least one element in the `tags` array has a property `name` with value of `"home"`:

```
result.filter(o => o.type === "EVENT" && o.tags.some(s => s.name === "home"));
```

**Demo:**

```js
let result = [{"type":"EVENT","id":"001","tags":[{"id":"98765","name":"home"}]},{"type":"EVENT","id":"002","tags":[{"id":"7654","name":"contact"}]},{"type":"EVENT","id":"003","tags":[]}];

let filtered = result.filter(o => o.type === "EVENT" && o.tags.some(s => s.name === "home"));

console.log( filtered );
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need `filter()` and use `find()` or `some()` to check exist name in tags.

```
var filter = result.filter(c=> c.type == "EVENT" && c.tags.find(d=>d.name == 'home'));
var filter = result.filter(c=> c.type == "EVENT" && c.tags.some(d=>d.name == 'home'));
```

```js
let result=  [
      {
        "type": "EVENT",
        "id": "001",
        "tags": [
            {
            "id": "98765",
            "name": "home"
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "EVENT",
        "id": "002",
        "tags": [
            {
            "id": "7654",
            "name": "contact"
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "EVENT",
        "id": "003",
        "tags": []
      }
    ]
    
    var filter = result.filter(c=> c.type == "EVENT" && c.tags.find(d=>d.name == 'home'));
    
    console.log(filter);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you simply want to select elements from the root array then filter is the appropriate way to do.
if you want to also transform the result (say, select the TAG object), you may use flatMap

```
result.flatMap( e => (e.type == 'EVENT' && e.tags.some(t => t.name==='home')) ? e.tags : [] )
```